# Facebook instant articles

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

The Facebook page shows characters as ???? for certain WordPress posts shared.

I did check the preview for Facebook Instant Articles for posts. It shows the same.
This only happens to certain posts.

I have also added following in header.

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I did also checked https://MYDOMAINAME/feed/instant-articles. There it shown correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try finding the language and maybe if it is thai this would work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="th">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874">
```

EDIT: maybe if one of the characters isn't in the charset it would be unreadable.
make sure you implement the right charset.

Comment: Did the same but same. It appears that some articles works. But for some its still in same. I could it find any difference. BTW Its Indian regional  language.